# How do I get Tomcat to stop writing over my [project].xml file in conf\Catalina\localhost when I start the server?

Tags: xml, eclipse, tomcat, localhost

I am having to re set up my project in Eclipse Helios and Tomcat 6 after getting a new PC. I have a [project].xml file in the conf\Catalina\localhost folder which contains some database login info for the development and test environments. Every time I start the server and go to my web app, the .xml file gets overwritten and my DB info is gone, making me unable to login to my app. If I take a good copy of the xml and paste it back in the localhost folder, then I can login, but it will be written over again when I run the server next time. I know there has got to be a setting somewhere for this because everything worked fine on my old PC. Where is this setting? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you're deploying from Eclipse, you can add configuration information by editing the context.xml or server.xml file directly. In the Package Explorer, look for the Servers node, which contains all of the tomcat configuration files. This is the file that Eclipse is using to overwite your file.

[image]

You can create multiple servers with multiple configurations this way as well. Also, make sure you do a `Clean Tomcat Work Directory` when you've changed it before you republish.

Comment: I have my old server.xml file and other files from my prior install. So that is all the same. But it didn't used to write over the xml, so I think it has to be a setting in Eclipse somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://alwold.blogspot.com/2008/05/getting-tomcat-to-stop-deleting-your.html) states you can stop this by setting the `autoDeploy="false"` in `server.xml`

Comment: I actually already had 'false' but it's not deleting the entire file like this article states. I had that problem at first but solved it by checking the 'publish module contexts to separate xml files'. Now instead of deleting the xml file, it just writes over it.